# Where is the error in JQuery function

Tags: jquery, function

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong:

I'm trying to create `id` for each children in specific element. The following code doesn't work:

```
$.get("/subject/list/", function(data){
    $("#subject-description-main-menu-list").children().each(function() {
        var pk;
        var subject;
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            pk = data[i]['fields']['pk'];
            subject = data[i]['fields']['name'];
        };  
        $(this).attr("id","subject_"+subject+pk);
    });
```

the rest of the code works fine!
And Google chrome console does not give me any errors,
but id of the elements do not change.

Comment: You don't describe what the "error" is.

Comment: You are overwriting `pk` and `subject` each iteration of your for loop, just fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you runs through the children to create a id for it?

in the for-loop you run through a data object and you set the pk and subject. the pk and subject always set with the last elements of the data object, because you runs through the whole data object and override pk and subject.

therefore pk and subject are always the same values. if you will set different ids for each children you not override pk and subject.

hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the data you get has `length == 0`. Try logging the data and see what it contains and if it has a length.

Comment: This should be a comment under the question.